# Laravel DigitalOcean API - Get newly created droplet login information

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5, digital-ocean

I'm new to the DigitalOcean API and I'm trying to get something done. When a user completes a step program, a new droplet will be created in the code. Now I need the login credentials for this newly created droplet. These are automatically sent via Email. I need these so I can connect with the created droplet and perform commands on it. How can I achieve the above? I tried doing `$droplet->user_data()` but unfortunately that does not work.

**Code**

```
public function store(Request $request, $id)
{

    $order = Order::find($id);

    $payment = Mollie::api()->payments()->get($order->mollie_transaction_id);

    $mainsettings = Session::get('main_settings');

    $webshop = $this->_webshopRepository->createWebshop();

    $addressData = [$mainsettings['region'], $mainsettings['city'], $mainsettings['postal_code'], $mainsettings['street_name'], $mainsettings['house_number']];
    $adres = $this->_addressRepository->createAddress($addressData);

    $mainsettingData = [$adres->id, $webshop->id, $mainsettings['store_name'], $mainsettings['store_tel'], $mainsettings['store_hoo'], $mainsettings['vat_number']];
    $mainsetting = $this->_mainsettingRepository->createMainSetting($mainsettingData);

    $images = DigitalOcean::image()->getAll(['private' => true]);
    $storeName = str_replace(' ', '-', $mainsetting['store_name']);

    // Here is where I am creating the droplet

    $droplet = DigitalOcean::droplet()->create($storeName, 'ams3', 's-1vcpu-1gb', $images[0]->id);

    $droplet->user_data();

    $commands = ["cd /home/", "rmdir test"];
    \SSH::run($commands, function($line){
        \Log::debug($line);
    });

    session()->forget('main_settings');
    session()->forget('chosen_theme');
    session()->forget('chosen_plugins');

    return $this->show($order, $payment);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here. The first, and most secure, is to add an SSH key to the Droplet when you create it. You will need to generate one locally and upload it to DigitalOcean. This can be done on the fly through the API or directly in the control panel. Then when you create the Droplet, pass in the ID of the key as the `$sshKeys` attribute. One thing to note here is that takes an array and can contain more than one key ID (See [the PHP library's docs](https://cdn.rawgit.com/toin0u/DigitalOceanV2/master/documentation/classes/DigitalOceanV2.Api.Droplet.html#method_create)).

If for some reason using SSH keys is not possible, you can create a new user on first boot and set its password by passing a cloud config script as the `$userData` attribute. A basic example, just creating a new user and setting a password would look like:

```
#cloud-config
users:
  - name: demo
    groups: sudo
    shell: /bin/bash
    sudo: ['ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL']
    passwd: $6$j212wezy$7H/1LT4f9/N3wpgNunhsIqtMj62OKiS3nyNwuizouQc3u7MbYCarYeAHWYPYb2FT.lbioDm2RrkJPb9BZMN1O
```

Note: `passwd` is not the password itself but its hash generated using:

```
mkpasswd --method=SHA-512 --rounds=4096
```

Check out "[An Introduction to Cloud-Config Scripting](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-cloud-config-scripting)" for a deeper dive.

Comment: I've been looking to understand the first option that you gave me. Is there a way you can show me an example of what you mean? I have to generate an SSH key and put some attributes in an array? How can I connect to the droplet by doing that? I appreciate the help.

Comment: Here's an intro to working w/ SSH keys: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/ssh-essentials-working-with-ssh-servers-clients-and-keys